# Inverse theorem on product of two convergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose I have two sequences, $a_n$ and $b_n$. I know that:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n=c$.

Does this mean that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ converges?

If so, by algebra of limits does it mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=c$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Any ideas on a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. We have that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n}=\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_nb_n}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n}=\frac{c}{1}=c,$$
since the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits if they exist and the last is not $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Last question here - what is the Tex syntax you used for the n->inf UNDER the limit, not next to it? It looks so much clearer!

Comment: The same you used, but when you have a separated equation, the subscript for the $\lim$ is under it.